# How to split the single field into multiple fields in logparser

Tags: logparser

I am very new to log parser. I tried using the different formats and delimiters but that that does not work for me. My log file looks like below..

```
# Version xx
# Feilds: date time c-ip
# Software : Weblogic
# Startdate : 2013-08-15 17:39:09
date value    time   ipaddress
```

When I appplied the following code

```
logparser.exe -o:DATAGRID "select * from abc.log_tmp"
```

where abc.log_tmp is the log file that contains the information

it gives the information in the following way:

```
******************************************************************
        logfilename                          index      content

 ******************************************************************** 
   C:xyx\abc.log_tmp                       3        date time

C:xyx\abc.log_tmp                       4        date time
**********************************************
```

when actually it should come like

```
date         time      c-ip


xxx          xxx       xxx
xxx          xxx       xxx
```

from this I came to know that it is taking date time c-ip value as one, but it should take it as different....

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly tell LogParser which input format it should expect (when you don't, Log Parser tries to figure it out from the filename or from the first few lines of the log file); in this case, it should work as you expect if you added "-i:W3c" to the command-line.